# What does exec $SHELL -l do?

Tags: shell-script

I have seen this command in a few different shell scripts:

```
exec $SHELL -l
```

...usually as an alternative to:

```
source ~/.profile
```

What exactly is `exec $SHELL -l` doing?

Answer (score 10):

The exec command replaces the current process image - the executable or program - with a new one, named as the argument to exec.  If $SHELL contains the name of an executable, as it usually does, exec will spin that exe up in place of the running shell.

HOWEVER, that's a very different action than just using "source" to read in a file of commands.  The source command read the named file and executes the contents line by line, *as though typed at the command line of the current shell.*

Answer (score 8):

It's invoking your shell (`$SHELL`) as a login shell.

*excerpt from Bash man page*

```
-l       Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell 
         (see INVOCATION below).
```

I suggest reading through the INVOCATION section of the man page for more information.

#### TL;DR;

Bottom line is that it tells Bash which files to source when it invokes. Either the `$HOME/.bash_profile` (`-l`) or the `$HOME/.bashrc` (`-i`).

#### References

- [Bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Comment: Pay it forward 8-)

Comment: Ah, so it sort of takes care of inconsistencies in bash profile file names?

Comment: You're launching a new shell. So if you've made changes to a shell config, running the $SHELL -l command would "apply" those changes. Running source ~/.profile would do so similarly without starting a new shell, except any variables or functions in your config that are not overwritten will remain set as they were initially.